# Multiple-domains on WAMP localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, system-administration, wamp, multiple-domains

If you're reading my question, thanks, I appreciate your help

I'm using Wamp on Windows Vista.

I've created 2 project folders:

```
www/project1/ 
www/project2/
```

My virtual hosts file looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project1/"
    ServerName project1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project2/"
    ServerName project2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone advise how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify ServerName in VirtualHost like this (and additionally ServerAlias) for each hostname:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host1.localhost"
    ServerAlias *.first.com first.com
    ServerName www.first.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host1.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host1.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ServerAlias *.second.com second.com
    ServerName www.second.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry pal, but what you're suggesting isn't working for me. See my Edit above in the original post. If you can help out from there, that would be great.

Comment: Hosts file must map first.com and second.com to localhost:

127.0.0.1    first.com
127.0.0.1    second.com

You need to make sure your local DNS is refreshed as welll; restart browser and restart dnscache service.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full tutorial, hope it helps. Let me know if you run into any problems.

http://kintek.com.au/blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/